Upgraded an ACC project to 2024 and I an not seeing the AEC Model API data
I added the AEC Model API app to my hub (us region) via clientID and upgraded a project to Revit  2024. I followed the steps in this tutorial (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/aecdatamodel-beta/v1/tutorials/tutorial-01a/) and when I got to navigating the design I got a 404.
[404 Not Found] Requested resource not found. No AEC data found for the provided hub id b.58bf5e56-7c96-41a9-be38-e7a4029b29da. This might be due to the absence of AEC data in the specified hub. If data extraction is currently underway, it may not have completed yet. Please consider querying 'aecDesignExtractionStatus' for extraction status and details

Any ideas ?
Thanks
